# How to edit a Google Form from script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

I've seen a lot of code snippets and API references online, but I've not been able yet to find **a simple guide on how to edit a Google form** with Javascript.

I've got a form linked to a sheet, I want one a drop-down list in the form to get its values from a column of the sheet. So I need to get the sheet, find the column, get the data and feed it to the widget.

I can't even see how to get to the form's script. A kick start would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Google has a JS-based scripting language to edit Drive features like Docs and Spreadsheet.

EDIT 1:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/your_first_script
There's also a convenient Google Scripts Editor. Create a google doc and look under 'tools'.
[script.google.com](http://script.google.com)

Comment: It seems to be what I need. It's funny that no matter what I've looked for by searching Google just didn't bring me to that page?

Comment: First, the example "managing responses from google forms" doesn't work for me. Second, I still haven't got any access to the actual source code of the form. How can I modify the form? Do I need to override it by getting objects and changing their attributes? There's not much explained in this introduction.